# Adobe Air - AS3 - Listing files in directory without the extension

Tags: actionscript-3, flash, air

I'm listing files in the "applicationDirectory" and getting the names with the extension,
For example "myVid.mp4".
I would like to get only the filename without the extension(mp4)

Here is my code so far

```
var subjDir:File = File.applicationDirectory.resolvePath("videos");
        var files:Array = subjDir.getDirectoryListing();
        var filesName:Array = new Array();
        for (var i:uint=0; i<files.length;i++)
        {
            trace(files[i].name);
            trace(files[i].nativePath);
            filesName.push({label:files[i].name,fpath:files[i].nativePath});

        }
```

Thank's in advance!

Answer (score 1):

```
trace (files[i].name.substr(0, files[i].name.lastIndexOf('.')));
```

Comment: use lastIndexOf instead of indexOf since file name could have dots.

Comment: Don't know how I've missed that. Thanks for pointing it out :)

Answer (score 0):

This will remove the file extension:

```
trace(files[i].name.replace(/\.[^\.]*$/,""));
```

Comment: Thank you! Works like a charm! Regex is hard! do you have a good guide about regex to give me?

Comment: Hi @Ompel, Take a look at [adobe help: Using regular expressions](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/ActionScript/3.0_ProgrammingAS3/WS5b3ccc516d4fbf351e63e3d118a9b90204-7fdb.html) or [this tutorial](http://regexone.com/)